# problems with Ruby dynamic method invocation

Tags: ruby, dynamic

I am building something on top of Elasticsearch's Ruby API and have the usual API issue of lots of almost identical functions that implement calls into the underly API and perform the error handling.  So I want to have one method which performs the messy stuff associated with the call to the underlying API:

```
 def perform_api_request( method, params ) 

  api_method = "#{@method_prefix}#{method}"
  puts api_method 
  begin 
    r = @es_conn.client.send(api_method, params )
  rescue => e 
    abort "there were errors calling #{method}:#{e}" unless extract_error(e) 
    return false 
  end 
  return true 
end
```

Which I am invoking:

```
      perform_api_request 'delete_template', { name: @name }
```

this outputs:

```
indices.delete_template 
there were errors calling delete_template:undefined method \
   `indices.delete_template' for #<Elasticsearch::Transport::Client:0x0000000282d758>
```

I have tried `self.send` and various other approaches but I can't get this to work.  All my efforts resulted in 'undefined method'.

Can someone point out what I am missing?

Comment: Method names don’t have dots in them (and send should be given a symbol).

Comment: send takes either a symbol or a string but I take your point about the dots.  I take it the first parameter of send should just take the last item (in this case 'delete_template') but I then can not see how to get the 'indices' into to the invocation.

Comment: exactly that   -- but i need more characters

Comment: Oh, right, strings are converted to symbols by “send”—my bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
r = api_method.split('.').inject(@es_conn.client) { |obj, m| obj.public_send(m) }
```

if you want to support arbitrary method chains. That would allow whatever dots you needed in `@method_prefix` and `method`. If you wanted to allow private methods too then:

```
r = api_method.split('.').inject(@es_conn.client) { |obj, m| obj.send(m) }
```

This assumes that you're controlling everything and not allowing any sort of outside input in `@method_prefix` or `method`; if you are allowing outside input then you'd really want to whitelist everything to avoid calling unexpected and dangerous methods.

Edit: if you need to pass parameters to the final call you need to do something like this:

```
api_method = "#{@method_prefix}#{method}".split('.')
last  = api_method[-1]
r = api_method.inject(@es_conn.client) do |obj, m| 
  m == last ? obj.public_send(m, params) : obj.public_send(m) 
end
```

to add the parameter to the final call.  There is probably a more elegant way of doing this ;)